# Golang: How to correctly parse UTF-8 string from C

Tags: c, utf-8, go

I'm a newbie to the go world, so maybe this is obvious.

I have a Go function which I'm exposing to C with the `go build -buildmode=c-shared` and corresponding `//export funcName` comment.
(You can see it here: https://github.com/udl/bmatch/blob/master/ext/levenshtein.go#L42)

My conversion currently works like this:

```
func distance(s1in, s2in *C.char) int {
    s1 := C.GoString(s1in)
    s2 := C.GoString(s2in)
```

How would I handle UTF-8 input here?
I've seen there is a UTF-8 package but I don't quite get how it works. https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/

Thank you!

Comment: Are you encountering a problem when reading the string?

Comment: Strings are just a sequence of bytes, and Go doesn't care what's in there.

Comment: @udo: Depends entirely on what's in s2in. It could point to a PNG file. Or UTF-16 text, or some ISO encoded text. Each case is different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special. UTF-8 is Go's "native" character encoding, so you can use the functions from the `utf8` package you mentioned, e.g. `utf8.RuneCountInString` to get the number of Unicode runes in a string. Keep in mind that `len(s)` will still return the number of bytes in the string.

See [this post in the official blog](https://blog.golang.org/strings) or [this article](http://dominik.honnef.co/posts/2012/04/dealing_with_encodings_in_go/) for some details.